# Vue router afterEach guard executes before loading has finished

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to create a loading animation when I navigate between routes. However, as soon as I click on a router link both beforeEach and afterEach guards execute immediately at the same time and only then my components starts to load.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
   console.log('starting...')
   store.isLoading = true
   next()
})

router.afterEach((to, from) => {
   console.log('finished!!')
   store.isLoading = false
})

new Vue ({
   el: '#app',
   router: router,
});
```

I put a heavy computation on component created method and it shows that the navigation has finished but only after 5 seconds my components loads.

```
export default {
...

  created()
  {
    doPointlessComputationsWithBlocking()
    this.fetchData()
  },
};
```

The console log shows this immediately after I click on a router link.

> starting...
>
> finished!!

Comment: What about if you move your `router.afterEach()` codes to component's `mounted()` ?

Comment: You probably need to use a lifecycle hook inside the component, since the routing takes place before any logic inside the component has ran.

Answer (score -1):

```
  async created()
  {
    doPointlessComputationsWithBlocking()
    await this.fetchData()
  },
```

Comment: i don't recommend this style. because created method should be synchronized not async
If you like this, your application must have the wrong cycle